# cs cart api integration to send order direct to distributer

Tags: php, xml, cs-cart

I   Just  customize my cs-cart theme and its working fine now main thing

i want to  integrate  the  cart functionality so that customer  order from my site and order

will directly go to distributor  on other main site .

Kindly help me how can i start integrating my `xml api`   cs cart.

If any other option  provided appreciated.

Itried from the root api.php  file but its giving me no-access error i set the edit profile  api access to  check yes and add the api key to my file .But not working.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With cs-cart api you can only export orders, will not automatically send to distributor.

You need to create a custom api that need to send order as it's created to the distributor

Comment: Thanks  for your response can you help me from where i need to start the api code in cs cart  i have API  detail for sextoyclub.com

Comment: Please send me a email here http://www.hungryweb.net/#additional_services and we start from there

Comment: ha haaa thanks for suggestion but i am low cost developer and working for other